# Sonos Cloud API HTTP POST always returns 500

Tags: rest, api, http, cloud, sonos

I'm trying to control my Sonos One (Gen 1) speaker through cloud APIs but all the POST request return 500 Internal Server Error without error message.

I generated an access_token as described in the documentation and was able to obtain information about the 'households' inside my network, finally both the group id and the player id.

I tried to obtain information about the status of the group by performing a GET on the following endpoint and it worked: 
`https://api.ws.sonos.com/control/api/v1/groups/{{group_id}}/playback`

Same with other GET requestes (e.g. groupVolume).
The problem arise when I try to make a POST (e.g. changing the volume or playing an audioClip), it returns 500 Internal Server Error without any body.

For all the requests I am using Postman including as Headers:

- Content-Type: application/json
- Authorization: Bearer [token]
- Content-Length: ??? (automatically inserted by postman)

while for the body of the *change volume* request I select the *raw* option and then select *JSON(application/json)* option.

The body is:

```
{
  "volume": 80
}
```

The endpoint is the following: `https://api.ws.sonos.com/control/api/v1/groups/{{group_id}}/groupVolume`

I also tried controlling the player with node ([Package](https://github.com/bencevans/node-sonos)) and it works.

Also tried to use Wireshark to see what requests the node-sonos package is performing but it seems it's not using the Cloud APIs.

I expect the player to change volume, but the API doesn't do anything and doesn't return any error message.

EDIT:
The cURL request from POSTMAN is the following:

`curl -X POST \
  https://api.ws.sonos.com/control/api/v1/players/<playerID>/audioClip \
  -H 'authorization: Bearer XXX' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'postman-token: XXX' \
  -d '{
    "appId": "edu.myInstitute.myName",
    "clipType": "CUSTOM",
    "name": "Test",
    "streamUrl": "http://...mp3_file_url"
}'`

Comment: That node package uses reverse-engineered LAN commands. It doesn’t go through the cloud, as you guessed. Can you post the “curl” output from the Postman request? Let’s get a look at the entire request.

Comment: My first guess is that that Content-Length header might be throwing things off. Any chance you could get Postman to remove that and try again?

Comment: Added it to the question

Comment: Confused: the text says you are doing a volume call, but the curl says you are doing audioClip. Assuming it is directed at a device that actually supports audioClip.

Comment: You are right, the cURL is for an audioClip, but it's the same, always return 500 (same with POST to volume call to change the volume). And yes, the device supports audioClip.

Comment: @Xfox we ran a version of your request here on our testbed and it worked. Can you reproduce this error, then email developer-feedback@sonos.com with the time window, Sonos household ID, and Sonos player diagnostic number? See support.sonos.com/s/article/141 for details on submitting system diagnostics. Please include your StackOverflow username as well.

Comment: @YvesGrantSonos sadly I don't have the device anymore and hence can't reproduce the issue. Thank you for your availability.